# error: incompatible types: 'Something' cannot convert to 'Something'

Tags: java, arrays

Here is my code:

```
public class ArrayFunctionExamples {

    // returns the mean of the array
    public static double mean(double[] a) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            sum += a[i];
        return sum / a.length;
  }

    // swaps array elements i and j
    public static void exchange(String[] a, int i, int j) {
        String temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;

  }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] a = new double[args.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        int arg = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        a[i] = arg;    
    }
    double value = mean(a);
    System.out.println(value);
    //Now, I want to print an new array by using the method of exchange
    for (int i=0; i<a.length;i++) {
        a[i] = Double.toString(a[i]);
    }
    String[] b = exchange(a,0,1);
    for (int i=1;i<b.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(b[i]);
    }

  }

}
```

Then; I get following error on my mac terminal:

```
ArrayFunctionExamples.java:78: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to double
            a[i] = Double.toString(a[i]);
                                  ^
ArrayFunctionExamples.java:80: error: incompatible types: double[] cannot be converted to String[]
        String[] b = exchange(a,0,1);
                              ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
2 errors
```

For the first error: a[i] is already a double; and I try to convert it to string; but the terminal tells me that 'String cannot be converted to double' (does my a[i] is a string here??? and method Double.toString try to convert it to double?)
And my second error tells me that a is a double. (i'm very confused here)

Then I tried following

```
String[] b = exchange(args,0,1);
System.out.println(b);
```

It tells my that void cannot be converted to String[]

Is there anyway to print my new array without change the original exchange method?

Comment: For the first error: `a[i]` is a `double`, and `Double.toString()` converts it to a `String`.  So far, great.  Then you take that `String` and try to assign it into `a[i]` which is a `double` (since `a` is an array of `double`).  That's where the error is occurring.  What were you trying to accomplish here?  You obviously wanted a `String`, but what did you want to do with it?

Comment: For the second error: `exchange` exchanges a couple elements of an array _in place_.  It modifies the array you pass it; it doesn't return the new array.  That's why it's declared as `void`.  So trying to assign the result into `b` gives you an error, because there's no result to assign.

Comment: @ajb  thanks for the explanation; I've fixed the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a[i] = Double.toString(a[i]);
```

The left-hand side, `a[i]`, is a variable of type double. The right-hand side, `Double.toString(a[i])`, is a value of type String. So you're trying to assign a String to a variable of type double, hence the error: you can't store a String in a variable of type double, because a String is not a double.

The second error is similar: The signature of the exchange method is `exchange(String[] a, int i, int j)`. So it expects an array of String as first argument. You're passing `a`. And `a` is declared as `double[] a`. So it's an array of doubles, not an array of Strings.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed this error by creating a new String[] : String[] b = new String[a.length];

        for (int i=0; i<a.length;i++) {
            b[i] = Double.toString(a[i]);
        }.